# Query duplications on left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query right here:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT 
matching.date,
matching.points,
matching.time,
matching.location,
matching.epos_id,
matching.rbpos_id,
matching.time_added,
rbpos_epos.epos_id,
rbpos_epos.rbpos_id,
rbpos_epos.location
FROM
matching
LEFT JOIN
rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id AND
matching.rbpos_id = rbpos_epos.rbpos_id WHERE
matching.user_id = ".$id_user." ORDER BY matching.time_added DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page;
```

So, the issue is, i have problems with this part:

```
 rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id AND matching.rbpos_id = rbpos_epos.rbpos_id
```

It won't work, no error or anything, but it won't give the desired results.

Both matching.epos_id /rbpos_id are varchar types.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

I.e

```
Matching column
ID  rbpos_id    epos_id
1   123         1234

Rbpos_epos
ID   rbpos_id    epos_id
1    123         1234
2    12          12
```

I should get the row one... because that's where matching.rbpos_id and matching.epos_id are equal to rbpos_epos.rbpos_id and rbpos_epos.epos_id

The echo

```
SELECT matching.date, matching.points, matching.time, matching.location, matching.epos_id, matching.rbpos_id, matching.time_added, rbpos_epos.epos_id, rbpos_epos.rbpos_id, rbpos_epos.location FROM matching LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id AND matching.rbpos_id = rbpos_epos.rbpos_id WHERE matching.user_id = 4171446415 ORDER BY matching.time_added DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: What do you mean "it won't give the desired results" ? What are the desired results ? What are the actual results ? What is the structure of your tables ?

Comment: the desired result is a table with the condition that, both columns on rbpos_epos, rbpos_epos.rbpos_id , rbpos_epos.epos_id should be equal to the row on matching , ie. matching.rbpos_id and matching.rbpos_epos_id

Comment: On the face of it, there's nothing wrong with this query - but it's generally better to provide the actual MySQL query rather than (or in addition to) the code that creates it - echo $query_pag_data;

Comment: Perhaps you have errant blank spaces in your query string or your data?

Comment: And what are the actual results (the not desired results you are getting) ?

Comment: I don't get matching.location..

Comment: What **do** you get ???

Comment: i just get matching.date and matching.points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve rows of `matching` that have matching rows in `rbpos_epos` you should probably replace `LEFT JOIN` with just `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

why not join on one condition and filter data in where condition :-

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT 
  m.date,
  m.points,
  m.time,
  m.location,
  m.epos_id,
  m.rbpos_id,
  m.time_added,
  r.epos_id,
  r.rbpos_id,
  r.location
  FROM
  matching as m
  LEFT JOIN
  rbpos_epos as r ON m.epos_id = r.epos_id WHERE
  m.rbpos_id = r.rbpos_id AND
  m.user_id = ".$id_user." ORDER BY m.time_added DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page;
```

Comment: @AlbAlb the structure you provide i have gone through this query with dummy data and it works fine..